# Uninitialized constant error in Ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine, rubymine-7

I have these two classes in RubyMine:

`book.rb`:

```
 class Book
   def initialize(name,author)
   end
 end
```

`test.rb`:

```
require 'book'
class teste
   harry_potter = Book.new("Harry Potter", "JK")
end
```

When I run `test.rb`, I get this error:

```
C:/Users/DESKTOP/RubymineProjects/learning/test.rb:3:in `<class:Test>': uninitialized constant Test::Book (NameError)
from C:/Users/DESKTOP/RubymineProjects/learning/test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a Rails app this error can also be caused by renaming the class without renaming the file to match, which was my issue when I found this error:

book.rb

```
class Book
  def initialize(name, author)
  end
end
```

book_test.rb

```
class BookTest
  harry_potter = Book.new("Harry Potter", "JK")
end
```

Answer (score 29):

You're getting the error because your `require 'book'` line is requiring some other `book.rb` from somewhere else, which doesn't define a `Book` class.

Ruby does not automatically include the current directory in the list of directories it will search for a `require` so you should explicitly prepend a `./` if you want to require a file in the current directory, ie.

```
require './book'
```

Comment: You should also [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it's the best one and helped you fix your problem. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for full details on all this stuff.

Answer (score 10):

You have defined the initialize method but forgot to assign the values into instance variables and a typo in your code triggered the error, fixed it as:

book.rb

```
class Book
  def initialize(name,author)
    @name = name
    @author = author
  end
end
```

test.rb

```
require './book'
class Test
  harry_potter = Book.new("Harry Potter", "JK")
end
```

So, which book or resource are you following? I think you should at least complete a book to get proper knowledge of Ruby and Object Oriented Programming. I would suggest you 'The Book of Ruby' to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Another rookie mistake (which I made) is to define a class inside a module but forgetting to put it inside a folder:

```rb
# This file should go inside a folder called `SomeModule` and it should be named `some_class.rb`
module SomeModule
  class SomeClass
    # ...
  end
end
```

I know it's not your case because of the class definition but I wanted to share it anyway.