# Name error when creating empty set in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, set

I'm trying to use the `Set` class from the standard Ruby library. I am creating an empty `Set` like so:

```
Set.new
```

but then I end up with this error:

```
main.rb:36:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Set (NameError)

Set.new
^^^
```

How do I properly create an empty instance of `Set`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninitialized constant error in Ruby class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133040/uninitialized-constant-error-in-ruby-class)

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff It's not quite the same, because it is class from (not core) standard library. Your link is about some developed class

Answer (score 6):

`Set` is standard Ruby class, but you need to require it just like any other class / module from the standard library (like `JSON`, `Date`, `Timeout`, etc.)

You need to add to the top of your `main.rb`

```
require 'set'
```

You can see it in the examples in the [official docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)

Comment: Thats one of the main differences between the Core and Standard Library.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
require 'set'
```

Top the top of your Ruby file main.rb